# Bundle script tags inside HTML files with Webpack?

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I'm just starting to modernize our front end build using Webpack 2. I've managed to make Webpack make a bundle out of our JavaScript files, however, we have significant amounts of code in `script` tags scattered throughout HTML files. I'd like to simply make Webpack find those script tags and add them to my bundle. They can execute in any order in the global context for all I care, but I want them to be able to `import` modules and stuff. Is this possible without having to rework my entire app?

Comment: You should just move those inline scripts into separate .js files and add those files to the scope for the bundle, if you plan on bundling them. Here's a reason why: how can webpack determine whether two inline scripts are the same if they're located in different places in two HTML files? It'd just add them as separate duplicate modules in the bundle, and you don't want that.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I would probably do something like rename the tags to `script-x` or something like that so they do not get evaluated twice. Unfortunately I can't move the scripts out that easily, I am trying to progressively upgrade the infrastructure of this app.

Comment: If you are able to rename each and every tag, you are able to move them into separate files, especially if you already have webpack configured for existing files. Don't make it harder for yourself by trying to incrementally update the infrastructure. It'll just make it harder to maintain in the long run.